# Few integration questions for the proof that $E[X^n] = n\int_0^\infty x^{n-1} \overline{F}(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

**Background:** I made learning probability harder than it has to be with my bad calculus skills.

**Problem:**

> Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable having distribution function $F$. Show that if $\overline{F}(x) = 1 − F(x)$, then
>
> $$E[X^n] = n\int_0^\infty x^{n-1} \overline{F}(x) dx$$

**My specific questions**

1. To go from step 2 to 3 $\color{blue}{(\text{blue numbers in screenshot)}}$ is it because $x^{n-1}$ can be thought of as a constant and $E[cX] = cE[X]?$

<s>2. Why is there still an $n$ in the final equality of the book solution? $\color{green}{\text{(green arrow in screenshot)}}$</s> **Edit: Book typo**

3. Before I used the solution I tried to solve directly... any hints if this is not a bad approach?

$$E[g(X)] = \int_0^\infty g(x) f(x) dx = \int_0^\infty n \int_0^\infty x^{n-1} \overline{F}(x) I_X(x) dx \, f(x) dx $$

4. Does this identity come up a lot in probability? (normally I'd use MGFs)

Thanks for your help and patience.

---

[image]

Comment: The problem quoted in the yellow part and the title  is wrong. There must  be factor of $n$ on RHS.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hmm the book question didn't have an $n$ on the RHS. I guess it was a book typo and probably answers my question 4... in that this identity is not super important to remember...

Comment: In the hint it must be $X^n=n\int_0^X x^{n-1}dx=n.\left.\frac{x^n}{n}\right|_0^X$.